# Puma not releasing memory after processing a request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

We are running a rails app on a docker container using puma. I have configured 5 workers each with a single thread on a 2 core 4 gb instance. Once we start using our app, after some time memory starts piling up, even after the request is processed by the puma worker it does not release the memory.

Container goes down after all workers utilize complete memory. The workers memory keeps on increasing if I send large requests.

Is this the normal behavior? Do I have to change some puma configuration? How do I address this. Help much appreciated.
Puma gem version-- 3.12.0
Ruby version - 2.5.3
OS - Centos 7

Comment: Container goes down after all workers utilize complete memory. The workers memory keeps on increasing if I send large requests.

Comment: Might want to share the code that shows what the workers are doing.

Comment: Looks like a memory leak. What is the beavior when you run the Rails app locally ? Also when you say "worker" this is Puma workers ? (Puma in clustered mode?)

Comment: Yes, it's puma workers. When we use phusion passenger we don't see such issues.

Comment: In development do you have the same 4GB machine ? Do you use 5 workers also ? How big is your app codebase ? Does the memory bloat happens when a specific task of your website is requested or straight after install ?

Comment: No memory shoots up during a specific task of the website. Yes this issue does occur even in development if we are working on that specific task. By default when app starts it utilizes only 300 mb of memory. But when we use phusion passenger none of these issues occur for the same code base.

Comment: Using 5 Puma workers will load much more Ram as the app will live in each worker. But it doesn't seem to explain the problem. Try to troubleshout the specific task for memory leaks. Otherwise start Puma with a single worker and monitor. If the bloat doesn't appear it may be because of the number of workers (yet I doubt it)

Comment: Will using preload_app in puma config help in this case?

Comment: Tried using preload_app and also upgraded puma gem both didn't help.

Comment: Comparing Passanger to Puma could misguide you... unless you paid for passenger, some concurrency features are disabled, resulting in some of your code behaving differently. Try comparing with iodine instead, so you get the same concurrency model (I'm iodine's author, I know some of the implementation details for these servers).

Comment: FYI: the Ruby GC is in charge of memory cleanup and only returns memory to the system if it knows the memory won't be needed again (I think that's on the 2nd or 3rd GC cycle in a row in which the memory remains unitized). Also, if you create different long-life object during runtime (instead of during startup), you will get memory fragmentation and the memory allocator won't be able to return the memory to the system.

Comment: Hi @KarthikK, Please share how you solved this issue. We are facing the same issue for puma.

Comment: We are not using puma, using phusion passenger